# We have 2 numbers: AB base 8 and BA base 7, where A and B are variables. If both of the numbers they have are equal, what is A + B?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, number-systems

We have 2 numbers: AB base 8 and BA base 7, where A and B are variables. If both of the numbers they have are equal, what is A + B?

I have attempted this problem, trying to convert both to base 10 and use those to compare the two, but I don't get an answer. Can someone help?

I keep getting 67 and 76, which would work only if 76 was a real number in base 7 .

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ in fact digits?

Comment: I am not sure...but if they weren't digits, then why would the question phrase AB and BA differently?

Answer (score 3):

$$8A+B=7B+A\implies 7A=6B$$
The integral solutions of $7A=6B$ are $A=6t,B=7t,t\ge0$. However, writing $BA_7$ implies that $A,B\in[0,7)$ and there is only one $t$ that makes $A,B$ fall in this range: $t=0$. Thus $A=B=A+B=0$.

Comment: So the answer is just 0? Thats a less interesting answer then I thought it would be.

Comment: @Smartsav10 Yes.

Comment: @Smartsav10 Me too, to be fair. The case you mention is of a special situation, where a number has a certain representation in a certain base and then has the reversed representation in another base, and I'd like to believe the general question itself would have some very interesting answers!

Comment: Generally one does not allow leading zeros in problems like this, especially two of them, but I agree there is no other solution here.  It is not a good problem to my taste.